# Get sample File URL for downloadable product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to get sample file url for a downloadable product[image]

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## In Block Inject Downloadable Sample Collection

```
public function __construct(
        .....,
        .....,      
        \Magento\Downloadable\Model\ResourceModel\Sample\CollectionFactory $sampleCollectionFactory,
    ) {
        .....,
        .....,
       $this->_sampleCollectionFactory = $sampleCollectionFactory;
  }
  
   public function getSampleCollection($productId){
                     $collection = $this->_sampleCollectionFactory->create();
                     $collection->addProductToFilter($productId);
                     return $collection;
          }
```

### In Phtml File

```
 $_mySampleCollection = $this->getSampleCollection(1); 
 foreach ($_mySampleCollection as $_sample): 
      {
       echo $_sample->getSampleUrl(); 
    }
```